# Localization of the standard MS Data Connection Dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, localization, database-connection

The [data connection dialog](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Connection) is a database tool component released with Visual Studio. It allows users to build connection strings and to connect to specific data sources. Its source code [has been released on Code Gallery](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdata/archive/2010/02/02/data-connection-dialog-source-code-is-released-on-code-gallery.aspx).

[image]

It's very useful, but the only problem is that its UI is always in English, regardless of the fact that it's run under a localized version of Windows.
**Maybe I missed some tricks?**
I tried to use it in a WPF app:

```
DataConnectionDialog dcd = new DataConnectionDialog();
DataConnectionConfiguration dcs = new DataConnectionConfiguration(null);
dcs.LoadConfiguration(dcd);

dcd.SelectedDataSource = DataSource.SqlDataSource;
dcd.SelectedDataProvider = DataProvider.SqlDataProvider;
...
if (DataConnectionDialog.Show(dcd) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
  ...       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bad news:** It's not localized by default
**Good news:** The project is easy localizable by adding the resources for the language that you need.

[image]

Comment: The only problem with that solution are legal constraints. The question is if you are allowed to translate Microsoft copyrighted content. I do not think so.